# How can I get the latest version of esniper?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I'm trying to install the `esniper` package on Ubuntu, and need the latest version as the older version doesn't work.  [Launchpad.net shows](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/esniper/2.33.0-2) that the package is available, and is in the Ubuntu standard library at the version I want (2.33) and `apt-get cache policy esniper` returns only this version:

```
apt-cache policy esniper
esniper:
  Installed: 2.31.0-1
  Candidate: 2.31.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.31.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-get update` doesn't seem to help the problem.  And trying to search for how to target the basic Ubuntu repository only turns up how to add PPAs which I don't think this is.

Comment: Your Launchpad link shows that `esniper` is, at present, only compiled for the "Artful Aardvark" (17.xx) release of Ubuntu. You're on Xenial. You _could_ download the source, apply the patches, and build the latest version yourself.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the error output when you try to run `sudo apt install esniper`. So far your question simply states that you think you have a problem, but not at all what the problem is.

Comment: What puzzling me is why do you want to install it when you already have it installed?

Comment: @waltinator has the right of it.  Didn't notice that 2.31 is the latest available for the build of ubuntu I'm on.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that 2.31 was the latest version for the build of Ubuntu I was on, 2.33 only available for other releases.  Workaround here was to download and compile from source (which did work)

1. [Download the source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/esniper/files/latest/download?source=files)
2. Unpack the code `tar xvf esniper-*.tar`
3. Configure `cd esniper-*/ && ./configure`
4. Install `sudo make install`

Your steps may vary if there are changes.

Comment: @Zanna - There ya go.  Though, not sure of the long term value, installation steps have a habit of changing.  In general (and in this case), download the source and read the README :)